# why Dagger could not recognize @Provides in AppModule?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am getting this error:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding]  SessionFetcher cannot be provided without an
>   @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. while you can
>   see I have defined SessionFetcher

in AppModule class

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(AccountViewModel::class)
  abstract fun bindAccountViewModel(accountViewModel: AccountViewModel): ViewModel

  @Binds
  abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelProviderFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule(private val applicationContext: Context) {

  @Provides
  fun sessionFetcher(@Named("UserPreferences") userPreferences: SharedPreferences): ISessionFetcher {
    return SessionFetcher(userPreferences)
  }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  @Named("UserPreferences")
  fun userPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(USER_CONFIG_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  }



class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(sessionFetcher: SessionFetcher) :
    SessionViewModel(sessionFetcher), AppComponent.Injectable {
```

Comment: Your code does not provide `SessionFetcher` in the `AppModule`. Just the `IServerTimeFetcher`. Does it extend/implement `SessionFetcher`? or is your code incomplete?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I have updated

Comment: I understand the issue  is connected  with interfaces but how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing `ISessionFetcher` inside your graph, but you're trying to `inject` an instance of `SessionFetcher`.

What you're providing to the graph is the type you can inject. Dagger does not analyze bodies of `@Providing` functions (or types for the eventual implementing class).

---

Just inject the interface instead of the implementing class.

```
class AccountViewModel @Inject constructor(sessionFetcher: ISessionFetcher) :
    SessionViewModel(sessionFetcher), AppComponent.Injectable {
    //...
}
```

if you need to use methods of `SessionFetcher` that are not exposed by the `ISessionFetcher`, then your `ISessionFetcher` is **probably** incomplete.